# How to run a Trigger in .sql file for DB2 command line

Tags: db2

I have a create trigger statement in a .sql file as 
Create  trigger INSERT
               AFTER INSERT ON INVENTORY REFERENCING NEW AS N
               FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
               BEGIN ATOMIC
     INSERT INTO staglog
     ( 
     stgokey1
     ,  stgnkey1
     )
     VALUES (

```
  ,  N.catentry_id
  ,  N.catentry_id
 );
```

When I am trying to execute the .sql file from command line for DB2, it gives me below error:
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following 
"N.catentry_id      )".  Expected tokens may include:  "".
LINE NUMBER=24.  SQLSTATE=42601

SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "N.catentry_id
     )".  Expected tokens may include:  "               ".

How can I fix this? Thanks.!

Comment: Please format the code before sending the question. It is very difficult to read your code and help you.

Comment: Also, it seems that you create a very similar answer soe hours ago. Still the same problem?